# Rotate video 180 with OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, video, rotation, video-capture

I'm a python beginner so sorry in advance for the mistakes.
I'm trying to rotate a video 180 degrees and then work with that video that I should have created.

At the moment I'm doing this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
    
#that's my original video - the one that I want to rotate 180 degrees 

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/Users/name/Desktop/VIDEO 12.05/PIC_P01.mp4')
    
    frame_number = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    
    # Original Frames
    frames = []
    for i in range(frame_number):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frames.append(frame)

    #here's where I try to rotate the video 
    new = cv2.rotate(frame, cv2.ROTATE_180)
    
    cv2.imshow('output', new)
     if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

    #here I'm trying to write the new rotated video
    newvideoR = cv2.VideoWriter('PIC_P01R.mp4',0x7634706d, 50, (360, 640))
    for jj in range(len(new)):
        newvideoR.write(new[jj])
    newvideoR.release()
    cap.release()
```

In the end, however, when I go to read the file I find only an empty file that I cannot open.
From this, I deduce that there is an error in the steps that I have made.
Would anyone have any advice on how am I suppose to do this?

** I've also tried to change the parameter on cv2.Videowriter (for example fps, size) but is still not working

Comment: Can you define "still not working"? Are you getting an output? Is the code failing? How do you know it is not working? Is there an error message you can post?

Comment: There was no error or warning message. The code seemed fine but in the end I simply could not open the video with any program (because it was an empty video).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to accumulate the frames, and write them in another loop.
You can read a frame, rotate it, and write it in the same loop.

- Get width and height:

  ```
   frame_width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
   frame_height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
  ```
- Open the output video file before the loop:

  ```
   newvideoR = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v"), 50, (frame_width, frame_height))
  ```
- Read the frame, rotate it and write it in a loop:

  ```
   for i in range(frame_number):
       ret, frame = cap.read()

       new = cv2.rotate(frame, cv2.ROTATE_180)

       cv2.imshow('output', new)
       if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
           break

       newvideoR.write(new)
  ```
- Release video reader and writer:

  ```
   newvideoR.release()
   cap.release()
  ```

---

Complete code sample (I named the files `input.mp4` and `output.mp4`):

```
import cv2
    
#that's my original video - the one that I want to rotate 180 degrees 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('input.mp4')
    
frame_number = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

# Get width and height
frame_width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
frame_height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

# here I'm trying to write the new rotated video
# Open the output video file before the loop, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v") = 0x7634706d
newvideoR = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v"), 50, (frame_width, frame_height))
    
# Original Frames
#frames = []
for i in range(frame_number):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    #frames.append(frame)  # No need to append the original frames

    #here's where I try to rotate the video 
    new = cv2.rotate(frame, cv2.ROTATE_180)
    
    cv2.imshow('output', new)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

    newvideoR.write(new)

newvideoR.release()
cap.release()
```

Comment: That worked well! Thank you very much for the clear explanation and the example.